A living forest
Basically, a forest with all trees connected to each other through underground roots, with nerves going through them. All of these trees are connected to the Mother Tree, that is essentially the 'brain' of the system. All trees have photoreceptors, that carry visual stimuli to the Mother Tree, which is conscious and monitors the entire ecosystem. If the Mother Tree detects a foreign predator or any other sort of danger, would it be possible for it to control the animals within the forest, to act against it? Or create a new creature within a 'womb'?

Considering that such a creature is completely made by you... 1) there is nothing science based upon which we can answer 2) you can decide that it does or does not.

You should check to see how much of this already exists. The largest single organism on our planet is a single-organism forest of quaking aspen named Pando. Plant-animal symbiosis has many examples. As for thinking trees, you're going to have to make that up as you go along, so we won't be able to help you there. Certainly not with science.

A couple of issues I see here. First, the forest you describe is actually not too far off from real world forests. Trees do actually communicate through the soil, using their roots & fungi messengers. You can google that on your favourite search engine. As for controlling animals, you will need to provide further details about the nature of trees & plants as well as the nature of the animals of your world. We can help you make your world, but we can't and won't make your world for you. As to creating a new kind of creature in it woody womb, you only get to ask one question at a time!

This is obviously the forest of Pandora from the movie Avatar. We do not answer questions about 3rd party or commecial worlds (VTC until corrected). You are required to explain how your world is different from the world of Avatar such that we can help you create "the concept of a mother tree connected through roots to all other trees of the same species throughout the world" in your world.

You can choose whether or not animals can be controlled. It's your world, you make the rules. How about saying "animals will be controlled, please justify this for me"?

@JBH The question is essentially asking about a hive-mind of trees. If you think something so simple is 'obviously the forest of Pandora' (not sure how, seeing as Pandora is a moon with forests growing upon it) then that is more an issue with that movie than this question. Unless you propose that we start closing every question involving supernatural mutation for 'obviously' being X-men/PAFL/etc.

I voted to close because of the breadth of the question. It is essentially  asking for design of the whole ecology, which is too broad for a precise single answer.

@IchthysKing Perhaps you've never seen the movie Avatar. The premise of the movie (meaning, the very thing the movie is about) is a hive mind of trees connected neurally across the planet with a Mother Tree that has the ability to control the forest's animals. People aren't allowed to skirt the rules just because they didn't name the film in their post and this isn't the first time we've had people use the site to "science-fy" someone else's fiction, but it's still off-topic.

@JBH -- To be fair, it also describes the forests in my own world, which predate Avatar.

@elemtilas  James Cameron ripped off your idea... that ugly bounder. I'll avenge your idea by refusing to pay full price for a ticket to Avatar 3! In the mean time, the OP's idea doesn't predate Avatar and the odds of contamination are magnificent.

@JBH Unless you're commiting some strange form of sockpuppetry you have no way to know whether or not the OP's idea came before or after they saw the movie (or even if they saw it at all)

@JBH better close every question about astronomy too, seeing as Star Wars exists

@IchthysKing (*eye roll*) The site has had a policy for a very long time that we don't help people with 3rd party/commercial worlds. The specific example was "how do I create a laser sword." Without knowing what's different between the querent's world and the Star Wars universe the question violates the policy. We have the same problem here. The OP is free to explain their difference. Were the idea from an obscure movie, I'd get your point, but Avatar is the highest grossing movie of all time, making this debate specious.

Trees in the forest do warn each other against pests by releasing chemical signals when there's an infestation going on. Animals react to these chemical signals, for example some pests are food for birds. Trees are also connected by fungal mycelium which they use to share nutrients, possibly share information that way. Plants do observe ambient light conditions and react by shifting spectral response of chlorophyll, as keeping photosynthesis rate in balance with their metabolism is crucial. They also notice surrounding vibrations, someone walking around. All of it already happens in nature, it's just quite slow. You can turn it to eleven, make it fast enough so that the forest actively reacts to whatever happens in the story.

This a frame challenge.
What you have is not a forest with trees.  Nor is it a largely underground giant animal which has hair or antler-like extensions protruding aboveground which look like trees.
So what you have is neither animal or vegetable, but something different combining aspects of both, if that is possible.
It is not a forest with trees.  The closest it could come to that is being a "forest" with "trees", and then only until the hypothetical human characters in your story realize that it is not the forest with trees they thought it was but something alien.  Once any hypothetical human characters in the story realize the true nature they will stop calling it "a forest with trees" and they will call it something else.
So it was an error on your part, as the omniscient author of the story, to describe it as:

...a forest with all trees connected to each other through underground roots, with nerves going through them.

When that short description includes proof that it is not a forest and that the seeming trees are not trees.
Furthermore, the title "A living forest" is rather misleading.  All forests contain many living things, planets, and animals, as well as some dead lifeforms.  The only thing which makes your "forest" a little different than a real forest is that it is a single living organism instead of many different living organisms.

Look at the aspen grove that clone themselves.  Pando is the largest, but there are many that are enormous single organisms that spread by suckers and so have many stems.
Consciousness would have to be something you add under your own rules.
